# Microsoft Visual Studio Project and c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I was looking to create new `c#` project, but there is no c# type is available in my `visual studio 2008` edition...

- Do I have to download some kind of
  plugin to run c# code?
- Where is it c# type project located, because I have
  searched and found nothing in the
  visual studio tabs...?

Comment: What version (specifically) are you using of Visual Studio 2008.  Is it professional, standard, or is it one of the express editions?

Comment: It is  Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 version 9.0.30428.1 SP1Beta1

Comment: Why do you have a Beta version of Visual Studio 2008 installed? Did you obtain this copy *legally*? That might be your problem. Note that the Express editions are free downloads; make sure you get the Express edition for C# if you want to use that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably installed it without the C# options, or if you are running the express edition there are seperate installations for each language

Comment: So Where can I download the installation language for c#?

Comment: Is it alright downloading visual c# 2008 express, the visual studio will recognize this??

Comment: @darkcminor - no, it would be a stand alone c# express installation then, it wouldn't affect your visual studio installation.

Comment: And to make execute c# code inside visual studio 2008, what do I do, I don't get it..

Comment: Re-run setup and run through a modify setup, add the C# language in.

Answer (score 0):

have u chked it in "Other Languages" in group tree of create new Project in VS??

u have to buy Visual studio which have C# in it, in order to run with